# city name in reversegeocoding

Tags: openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to get city name from reverse geocoding. Problem is for some geo location it is showing city name but for some it is other details like county, suburb. It is hard for me to use the data as it is changing place to place.

Here is the example.

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=24.7040592&lon=77.10249019999999&format=json&json_callback=my_callback&extratags=1

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat=54.9824031826&lon=9.2833114795&zoom=10&extratags=1

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=28.5113627&lon=77.2330641&format=json&json_callback=my_callback&extratags=1

If you check the output of above links then you can see the difference.

Is there any way I can get the Country Name, Zip code, and City name properly.

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i am using angular but it doesn't make any difference. If i simply paste it in browser then also it is not showing me city name. It should be unified then i can use it in angular.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/63279/city-name-in-reverse-geocoding